# c# delegate and event handler between two classes

Tags: c#, class, delegates, event-handling

I'm learning delegate and event hadler because i need in my code. In the example, the Class Test generates the message **Hello, i'm an event!**
From this Class i need to call the method Evento1 in Class Test1, to generate the message **Hello, i'm another event!** But i'm not able to do it.
I tryed to instantiate the Class Test1 and call the method. The debuger compile but the second message don't appear.

```
namespace Eventi1
{
    // Delegate declaration
    delegate void testEventHandler(object source, string message);
    class Test
    {
        // Event
        public event testEventHandler testEvento;

        // Function that triggers the event
        public void Evento(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event!");
            if (testEvento != null)
            { testEvento(this, message); }

            Test1 evento = new Test1();
            evento.Evento1("Hello, i'm another event!");
        }
    }

    class Test1
    {
        // Event1
        public event testEventHandler testEvento;

        // Function that triggers the event
        public void Evento1(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event1!");
            if (testEvento != null)
            { testEvento(this, message); }
        }
    }

    public class EventSample
    {
        // Constructor
        public EventSample() { }
        static void Main()
        {
            // Classe instantiation
            Test b = new Test();

            // Event handler
            //b.testEvento += new testEventHandler(onTestAction);
            b.testEvento += onTestAction;

            // Event invocation
            b.Evento("Hello, i'm an event!");
        }

        // Function that triggers the event
        public static void onTestAction(object source, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We're inside the event handler.");
            Console.WriteLine("Messagge: " + message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

PS second question to Aansari

```
class Test
{
    public delegate void testEventHandler(object source, string message);
    public event testEventHandler testEvento;

    // Function that triggers the event
    public void Evento(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event!");
        if (testEvento != null)
        { testEvento(this, message); }

        Test1 evento = new Test1();
        evento.testEvento += testEvento;
        evento.Evento1();
    }
}

class Test1
{
    public delegate void testEventHandler(object source, string message);
    public event testEventHandler testEvento;

    // Function that triggers the event1
    public void Evento1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event1!");
        if (testEvento != null)
        { testEvento(this, "Hello, i'm another event!"); }
    }
}

public class EventSample
{
    public EventSample() { }
    static void Main()
    {
        Test b = new Test();
        b.testEvento += onTestAction;
        b.Evento("Hello, i'm an event!");
    }

    // Function that triggers the event
    public static void onTestAction(object source, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We're inside the event handler.");
        Console.WriteLine("Messagge: " + message + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: _I tryed to instantiate the Class Test1 and call the method. The debuger compile but the second message don't appear._  Correct, because you haven't subscribed to `testEvento` in class `Test1` (you've only subscribed to the event in class `Test`).  Note that you are subscribing to an event only of that particular instance, not a "commonly named event across classes", or even multiple instances of the same class.

Comment: I thank you but unfortunately I have understood very little of what you told me. Can you please explain it in a simpler way or correct the code. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporate the following change and it will give you expected result

```
Test1 evento = new Test1();
evento.testEvento += testEvento;
evento.Evento1("Hello, i'm another event!");
```

The problem in your code was, though you were assigning event handling method to `Test` class event handler, you were not assigning any event handling method to `Test1` class event handler.

Comment: And what if i move `delegate void testEventHandler(object source, string message);` iside Class Test and Test1? `evento.testEvento += testEvento;` generates: You can not implicitly convert the 'Events1.Test.testEventHandler' type into 'Events1.Test1.testEventHandler'

Comment: There is a concept of Type compatibility of delegate. Please go through this [Type compatibility and Parameter compatibility of delegates in C#](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3016/type-compatibility-and-parameter-compatibility-of-delegates-in-csharp)